# Use storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage to add tags to an s3 object

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-storage

My question is around tagging s3 objects using `S3BotoStorage`.

Through `boto3` you can add tags to an s3 object before uploading it to an s3 bucket.

[this it the documentation for tagging s3 objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-tagging.html)

I was wondering if there is a way to add tags to an s3 object if the method of uploading is `storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage`.

Thanks!